# how to create a SSRS custom shared schedule

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to create a custom shared schedule which should take value from database. Is it something possible in SSRS? Please help

Example- Report should run after billing is done. The billing finishes after the first or second week. This information is stored in db

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check out [Data Driven Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-a-data-driven-subscription-ssrs-tutorial?view=sql-server-2017) - if you have the Enterprise version.

With a data driven subscription, you have a query that can check your db for data. If your query returns no results, the report doesn't run. You'd have to schedule it for each day and also make sure it doesn't return data after the first time (i.e. it always checks for just today's [or yesterday's] data)

If you don't have the Enterprise Edition, you could create your own stored procedure to check your data and then fire off your report if it should be run. Then you'd need to create a job in SSMS to run it on a schedule.

To run your subscription, you'd need the Subscription ID for the EDIT link of the subscriptions page in the Report Manager.

```
EXEC dbo.AddEvent @EventType = 'TimedSubscription', @EventData = @SUBSCRIPTION_ID;
```

[MS SQL Tips - Simulate Data Driven Subsciptions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4249/simulate-reporting-services-data-driven-subscriptions-on-unsupported-editions/)

Comment: Thanks...Got your point but I have 100s of reports to follow the shared subscription. Do i need to create data driven subscription for every report thats going to follow the shared schedule?

Comment: @Som  Ugh - yes. If they are all depending on the same data, then the stored procedure might be easier. You can create a loop after the data check to EXECUTE the AddEvent for each subscription.